# Stack Exchange should submit a copy of your message when you send a support request

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I noticed that when I get an automated email about a support ticket after writing to Stack Exchange, I don't see a copy of the message I wrote.

I do tend to work with more media-specialized organizations when I send emails so it might just be what I am used to, but I haven't seen a group or business that doesn't include a copy of the original message in a real long time so I wouldn't think to copy and paste the original message.

Having it just makes the conversation more continuous and I honestly don't see what the harm would be in including it for the ticket. Is there a specific reason Stack Exchange doesn't do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The support system is already prone to abuse, and sending a copy of the message would only make that worse.

For a long time we didn't send any kind of auto-response at all, because the contact form is not validated and anyone can type any email address into that box and bother whoever owns that email with an auto-response. Sending what they typed into the box along with it only exacerbates that problem. Now some random user is receiving a potentially spam or abusive message from *our* email address in the form of a confirmation of receiving some ticket they didn't submit.

Unfortunately the way we do support does not make these options viable. We've already been experiencing issues with confused users receiving confirmations for stuff they didn't submit in the couple weeks we've had the option turned on. We will likely be turning the auto-responders back off sometime in the near future for community support requests.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I do see a solution though: simply have the site send contact emails from an actual account instead of letting people type in any random email. If the site automatically links a support ticket with the account it is relevant to, which is what I see many other websites do, then it would seem to solve that problem.

Comment: @John We can't do that. Users who are having trouble accessing their account still need to be able to contact us. There are plenty of users trying to regain access and don't even remember what email was tied to it.

Comment: But they could be required to create a new or temporary account for that then (which would additionally slow down spammers), associated with the email they are temporarily using, and I haven't seen support agencies of other sites that are against that when someone is locked out of their original account. If they are sending a message when they could be using any random email to make an account, then it would stand to reason they have some other identifying piece of information anyway, otherwise contacting the site wouldn't help.

Comment: @user134300 Autoreply is currently enabled, I can confirm that after sending a support request. This topic is simply about the content of that auto reply, not whether it will continue to be implemented. I agree that it's common sense for a website to confirm they received a message so that the sender knows they aren't ignored.

Comment: Does this declined request also include personal mails to our complaints and requests to the team?

Comment: @NogShine I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @animuson I'm sorry for an unclear comment. I received a copy of the report a couple of months ago. Is this change new? i.e., after new policy? Does the Stack Overflow team still sends personal responses to our requests and complaints or our requests will be approved but without our notice?

Comment: @NogShine We used to send a copy of the message *when we replied*. We didn't use to have an auto-responder at all. This request is to include a copy of the submitted message with the auto-responder email. We still send a copy when we reply to the message, as always.